# Return a C array and read it in main.c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to open the file "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte" and print it out. When I print it in read.c it works fine, but when I try to read the returned array in main.c it does not work (it prints the first 3 digits correctly, but after that it only prints 0s.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

read.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LABELSIZE 4542
#define OFFSET 8

char * test_labels() {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte", "rb");
  static char buffer[LABELSIZE-OFFSET];

  fseek(file, 8L, SEEK_SET);
  fread(buffer, 1, LABELSIZE-OFFSET, file);

  /* int i; */
  /* for(i=0; i<=LABELSIZE-OFFSET; i++) { */
  /*   printf("%d ", buffer[i]); */
  /* } */

  fclose(file);
  return buffer;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "read.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LABELSIZE 4542

main() {
  //  char buffer[LABELSIZE-8];
  char* buffer = malloc(LABELSIZE-8);
  strncpy(buffer, test_labels(), LABELSIZE-8);

  int i;
  for(i=0; i<LABELSIZE-8; i++) {
    printf("%d", buffer[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: try memcpy, not strncpy. strncpy will stop at the first byte that has a value of zero. It is for copying null terminated strings, not an array of bytes. strncpy fills all bytes after the first zero with more zeros, which explains what you are seeing.

Comment: @SectoKia: that could be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try memcpy, not strncpy. strncpy will stop copying at the first byte that has a value of zero. It is for copying null terminated strings, not an array of bytes. strncpy fills all bytes after the first zero with more zeros, which explains what you are seeing